# Accessing Drupal 6 data using Drupal 7 entities

Tags: 7, entities, database

I have a project where we have a legacy system built in Drupal 6 that has been heavily customized, with much of the data stored in custom tables.  We are currently planning a D6 to D7 upgrade, but we have an immediate need to access that data in a Drupal 7 instance, leaving the D6 site intact for now.

I would like to access that data using Drupal Entities and wrap each D6 table in a Drupal 7 Entity; however I'm having trouble making that work since the underlying assumption with the Entity API is that the data is stored in the local database, and this database is remote.  We can access the database directly from the Drupal 7 instance, and I have the database credentials loaded in settings.php.  I can query the data using Database::getConnection('default', 'legacy')->select(), so I know my connection is good; however I have no idea how to go about structuring an Entity class so that I can leverage EFQ, Views, etc. on this data.

I looked at Remote Entity API, but I"m not dealing with a RESTful service here, I have a direct connection to the D6 database.

Any assistance or hints would be greatly appreciated.  I've worn Google out.

Comment: Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 data is heavily incompatible. Either you will have to practically rewrite entities from the ground up, or give up this idea, and follow classic solutions: 1) Migrate content to new site or 2) Start RESTful server on Drupal 6, and let it continue to handle your data.

Comment: @Mołot Luckily enough, someone's already done it

Comment: @Clive OP already said "I looked at Remote Entity API, but"

Comment: Lisa, the question "Any assistance or hints" is a bit broad, but you can override an entities load function to fetch the data from anywhere you want, including a second database with custom content. I'd be happy to discuss the topic further in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/327/drupal-answers)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're discounting the Remote Entity API module because you don't have a RESTful service...

The module actually relies on the [Web Service Clients](https://www.drupal.org/project/clients) module, which provides that REST service for you:

> Parallel to the Services module, the Clients module provides the ability to implement pluggable clients to external web services, including external Drupal sites running the Services module, the main use case being connecting to other Drupal installs via the Services module with either the REST or XMLRPC server.
>
> Clients module allows you to create connections to remote services with an admin UI. These handle fetching a result from a remote service. Different types of connection are provided for different types of services. **There is a Drupal client connection type for different versions of Services (5.x-0.92, 6.x-2.x, 7.x-3.x), hence Clients can be used to connect to sites with different versions of Drupal.**

Emphasis mine.

Comment: OP already said "I looked at Remote Entity API, but". Seems she already tried this solution and does not want it; prefers direct database connection.

Comment: @Mołot _but I"m not dealing with a RESTful service here, I have a direct connection to the D6 database._ suggests to me the OP is discounting solutions on false information - using this module you have an implicit RESTful connection. Unless there's another hidden gem of a module which magically exposes remote db connections as local ones, the only alternative I can think of is "write it from scratch".

Comment: Oh, if you're right, then good. I understood it more like she wanted to discard soon-unsupported d6 and use it's DB directly with 7.

Comment: Yeah you may well be right, I could easily have got that wrong. But as your first comment on the question rightly alludes to, to make this happen you need some sort of translation layer between D6 and D7 data. REST feels like an infinitely better option than actually coding that layer as D6 CCK -> D7 fields

Comment: Explain to me why I would need the Clients module.  I'm not dealing with a REST api, I have a direct database connection.  I simply want to query the remote legacy database instead of the local database.  Right now the legacy system continues to live and is being used on a daily basis, so migrating the data to D7 is not currently an option.  So, I'm failing to see where the Clients module has any role here, please enlighten me.  I can use the Database functions in Drupal 7 to do this, but I would prefer to leverage the Entity API if possible so that I can in turn leverage Views.

Comment: Also, D6 REST is not an option -- it's unsupported and has too many security issues associated with it at this time.

Comment: The clients module **provides a REST API for your Drupal 6 site**, that's why you would need it. I'm offering this to you as an alternative to the gut-wrenching amount of code you'd have to write if you want to expose the entity system to a remote database, which it was never intended to do. There's a good reason you haven't been able to find alternative suggestions with Google - it's a difficult and laborious feature to implement.

Comment: And that's just if you're going from Drupal 7 -> Drupal 7. What you're asking for is a fully-fledged, on-the-fly, translation layer from D6 data to D7 entity API, exposed over a remote database connection, with full API support. It's just not going to happen. Standardising your data into REST, though, which makes it version-agnostic, is distinctly possible. Hence this answer.

Comment: Lisa, I'm not trying to argue with you here - I'm telling you what solutions are available to you that don't involve writing a lot of code. Yes, there are other issues you'll need to overcome if you want to achieve this very advanced functionality, I'm just giving you, and anyone else who's trying to do this, one of the options. You don't have to do it this way, I'm not trying to force you to. But it would hardly be in the interests of our community for this question not be answered just because you don't want to implement it this way, when it's a viable solution to your problem.

Comment: From the documentation on the Clients module, you have to implement Services on the D6 site in order for the Clients module to actually with the D6 site to provide the REST API as you referenced.  https://www.drupal.org/node/2012982 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2125265 make D6 Services NOT a viable option due to security implications, as I had mentioned earlier, so the suggested solution of using Remote Entity API and Clients is not an option -- we will not be implementing Services on the D6 site.

Comment: Not quite, it's an option you _won't consider_. It's still a viable solution to the posed problem. But, like I said, I'm just trying to help you understand quite how mammoth a task you're trying to take on here, and offer an alternative way to get the results. Ignoring this option is perfectly fine, perhaps it will be sufficient for somebody else in future, though.

Comment: @LisaRidley Read [this](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/remote-entities-in-drupal-7/2012-10-25), it explains why remote entities are so hard to implement in D7, and why you can't have access to the full API when using them. All you need to do is substitute the 'web service' part of their solution with your translation layer of D6 -> D7 entity/field data, and you have everything you need

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would properly migrate the data from the old database into Drupal 7.

I would plan out the entities in the new site that will take the data from the old site. They may be nodes, custom entities, [data module](https://www.drupal.org/project/data) tables, users, taxonomy terms, etc.

Then I would migrate the data from the old database into those native Drupal 7 entities.

Then I would completely do away with the old legacy database.

By hanging on to the old database and somehow hacking it into your new website you are adding much unnecessary complexity and it will likely cause you lots of headaches in future.

As for the migration, I would use the [Migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate), the [Migrate extras module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_extras) and depending on your needs maybe the [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d).

The migrate module is fairly complex and has a bit of a learning curve but is very powerful. It follows consistent patterns though so once you've learned it it's not so scary.